# Analytic solution of the $3\times3$ symmetrical ODE system $x'_i=-x_i\cdot(x_i-\bar{x})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, geodesic

> Consider the following system for $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ positive:
>   $$\frac{dx_{i}}{dt}=-x_{i}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)\qquad\text{where}\ \bar{x}=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}$$ Given a starting point such that $x_1x_2x_3=1$, it is easy to show that the system remains on the surface $x_1x_2x_3=1$ and heads towards the stationary point $x_1=x_2=x_3=1$. Is it possible to find an analytic solution, so that one could calculate where the system is at time $t$?

I've noted that the system is in generalized Lotka-Volterra form, and I've been wondering whether the system travels on a geodesic, but I don't know how to show this, or whether it would be useful.

Comment: From a rough dynamical system analysis it seems to me that the system should converge to the fixpoint $x_1=x_2=x_3$ as long as $x_1x_2x_3 = r > 0$ (this quantity is conserved along the flow). I can't see how to solve it analytically however if you consider the simpler case with only $2$ variables instead of $3$ (so that $\overline{x} = (x_1+x_2)/2$) then it looks like this is possible.

Comment: Thank you @Winther. I have the solution for 2 variables but unfortunately I need it for 3.

Comment: Does it go along a geodesic/straight line for $2$ variables?

Answer (score 0):

Running a few numerical solutions, it appears that if x3>x2>x1, this always remains the case, and that x3 monotonically decreases, x1 monotonically increases, but the time derivative of x2 may change sign.

Comment: By considering that $x_1 x_2 x_3 = 1$ is symmetrical in the planes $x_1=x_2$, $x_1=x_3$, $x_2=x_3$, it's clear that the inequality is maintained during the evolution of the system, as the system cannot cross the lines of symmetry of the surface to which it is bound. In the case that $x_3>x_2>x_1$, it is always the case that $x_3>\bar{x}$ and $x_1<\bar{x}$, so $x_3$ and $x_1$ and monotone decreasing and increasing, respectively. $x_2,x_3$ can only take values in the region $x_3>1$, $x_3>x_2$, $x_3>\frac{1}{x_2^2}$.